# How to center google map v3 using jquery.gmap.js

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, center

How can I center (viewpoint) my google map v3 using jquery.gmap.js ( http://labs.mario.ec/jquery-gmap/jquery.gmap.js ).
I have two or more markers in the same city, but I want to centering the map in specific point on the map ( or centering coordinates on the first marker ).
My jquery is :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{  
 $('#map_canvas').gMap({            
    zoom: 16,
    markers:[
        {
            latitude: 51.51793,
            longitude: -0.140419,
            html: 'some_text_1',
            popup: true,                    
        },
        {
            latitude: 51.52028,
            longitude: -0.122766,
            html: 'some_text_2',
            popup: true,    
        }
    ]
});
```

});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to set value of 'popup' to false, otherwise gmap will center the second marker. Following is the updated js code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#map_canvas').gMap({
        zoom: 16,
        markers: [{
            latitude: 51.51793,
            longitude: -0.140419,
            html: 'some_text_1',
            popup: false,
        }, {
            latitude: 51.52028,
            longitude: -0.122766,
            html: 'some_text_2',
            popup: true,
        }]
    });

    $('#map_canvas').gMap('centerAt', {
             latitude: 51.51793,
            longitude: -0.140419,
            zoom: 16
        });
});
```

Here's the fiddle...[gmap-fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dFjdy/81/)

Comment: Thanks, if I have one or two more markers and I need "popup: true" it center the last marker, is that right ?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by calling the following line after the `.gMap({ ... })`

```
$('#map_canvas').trigger('gMap.centerAt', [lat, lng, zoom])
```

Comment: So it be like this, is that right ?

"$(document).ready(function()
{  
 $('#map_canvas').gMap({ ... } );
$('#map_canvas').trigger('gMap.centerAt', [51.51793, -0.140419]);

});"